# JS onsubmit clashing with other validation onsubmit

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a form with an inline onsubmit to set a variable "submitted" but the validation plugin I am using also uses onsubmit, and so isn't allowing my inline one to be 'fired'

Is there another way I can fire the variable when the validation is passed and the form is actually submitted?

```
<form action="url-on-separate-domain" method="post" id="primary-form" name="primary-form" target="hidden_iframe" submit="submitted=true">
...
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var submitted=false;
</script>

<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted) {window.location='thankyou.html';}"></iframe>
```